# How do I get rid of the warning <Class> may not respond to <Selector>?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

The below code behaves as expected however the compiler keeps telling me this:
warning: 'StatusViewController' may not respond to '-beginLoadingThreadData'

How do I get rid of that warning and most important why xcode believes that is the case?

here is my code:

```
[self beginLoadingThreadData]; // called in the loadDidView block

- (void)beginLoadingThreadData
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadThreadData) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)loadThreadData
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finishedLoadingThreadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}

- (void)finishedLoadingThreadData
{
    [[BusinessLogic instance] startTracking:self];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare that method before you use it. I'm assuming it's a private method, in which case you would add a class extension at the top of the implementation file:

```
@interface MyClass ()
- (void) beginLoadingThreadData;
@end
```

If it's a public method, make sure you've declared the method in your header and `#import`ed the header at the top of the implementation file.

Comment: I must have checked 3 times and I saw the declaration... more than an app I need an eye doctor - thanks Peter!

Answer (score 1):

You have to either move the definition of `loadingThreadData` before the definition of `viewDidLoad`, or define it in the header file for `StatusViewController`, for example by inserting `-(void)beginLoadingThreadData;` before the @end in the header file (probably `StatusViewController.h`).

The reason is that if you don't do this, when the compiler reached your `viewDidLoad` method, and sees the call to `beginLoadingThreadData`, it has not yet seen the definition of `beginLoadingThreadData`, and hasn't been assured (by seeing a declaration with the method signature in the header file) that such a definition exists. Therefore it warns you that the method you're trying to call might not exist.